# Is 'try / finally' the best way for me to handle (and close) this long-running IMAP4 connection?

Tags: python, exception-handling

I'm writing a script to archive email messages from one IMAP folder to another. It looks, more or less, like the following. I've obfuscated about 30 lines unrelated to this question:

```
import imaplib
import getpass

def main():
    user = getpass.getuser() + '@mymailbox.com'
    mailbox = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('mymailbox.com', 993)
    try:
        mailbox.login(user, getpass.getpass())
    except imaplib.IMAP4.error:
        raise RuntimeError('Credential error.')
    mailbox.select('my_mailbox')

    # Here lies some 30 lines not relevant to the question, but which
    # find mailbox messages, copies them to another folder, and
    # sets the delete flag in 'my_mailbox'.

    try:
        mailbox.close()    # which also expunges the mailbox
    except:
        pass
    mailbox.logout()
```

After working with my IMAP server for a while, I've discovered a fair amount of unexpected error conditions arising from its implementation of [RFC 3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501). No matter what, however, I always want to attempt `mailbox.close()` and `mailbox.logout()`.

It sounds like a good occasion for a [`try / finally` block](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#try), and that usage is supported by [other examples](http://pymotw.com/2/imaplib/#deleting-messages). All the same, it feels unnatural to wrap some 40 lines of `main()` execution in a try-block:

```
def main():
    user = getpass.getuser() + '@mymailbox.com'
    mailbox = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('mymailbox.com', 993)
    try:
        try:
            mailbox.login(user, getpass.getpass())
        except imaplib.IMAP4.error:
            raise RuntimeError('Credential error.')
        mailbox.select('my_mailbox')

        # Here lies some 30 lines not relevant to the question, but which
        # find mailbox messages, copy them to another folder, and
        # set delete flags in 'my_mailbox'.
    finally:
        try:
            mailbox.close()    # which also expunges the mailbox
        except:
            pass
        mailbox.logout()
```

Is that a common pattern? I could also write my own [context manager](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with); perhaps that's the better way to go. What's the best practice for long-running connections like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the working logic into its own function

```
def process_mailbox(mailbox):
    user = getpass.getuser() + '@mymailbox.com'
    try:
        mailbox.login(user, getpass.getpass())
    except imaplib.IMAP4.error:
        raise RuntimeError('Credential error.')
    mailbox.select('my_mailbox')
    #whatever else

def main():
    mailbox = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('mymailbox.com', 993)
    try:
        process_mailbox(mailbox)
    finally:
        try:
            mailbox.close()    # which also expunges the mailbox
        except:
            pass
        mailbox.logout()
```

Comment: Stunningly obvious, in retrospect. Any thoughts on `with` vs. `try / finally` here?

Comment: @Christopher, the `with` gets really helpful if you need to do this a lot. If this is the only function where you do it, it wouldn't seem all that people.